# Finding $\Omega(f(n))$

Tags: functions, asymptotics

Is there a standard way to find a $\Omega$ of a function $f(n)$ ?

I mean, I'm trying to understand how to determine:

$$g(n)=\Omega(f(n))$$

where $f(n)$ is a polynomial or logarithmic function

I understand the definition by which:

$$g(n)=\Omega(f(n)) \iff g(n)\ge cf(n), n>n_0, c>0, n_0>0$$

But I just can't understand what to do to get $g(n)$ given $f(n)$

Looking for examples I found that:
$\log(n!) = \Omega(n\log(n))$

But I still can't understand how to explain that result and I'm not able to sort this out:

$$n^2\log(n) = \Omega(??)$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Equations" like $f=\Omega(?)$ and $?=\Omega(f)$ don't have unique $?$'s...

Comment: Ok, but how can I get to one of the solutions? Trying with different c and $n_0$ ?

Comment: Just one of the "solutions"? Well, dividing $f$ by any $g=\Omega(1)$ works, i.e. $f=\Omega(f/g)$...

Comment: The point is that $c$ and $n_0$ don't matter.  You need some values for a particular problem, but we don't care what they are.  All that matters is the behavio(u)r as $n \to \infty$.  If you think only about polynomials, you only care about the order of the leading term.  $.000001x^n \gt 10^{100}x^{n-1}$ eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you apply [these explanations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72412/big-and-small-o-notation-help/72421#72421) about the $o$ and $O$ notations to the setting of the $\Omega$ notation. The take home message is that $\Omega(f(n))$ is in fact a class of sequences $(g(n))$ and not one particular sequence $(g(n))$. For example, if $g(n)=\Omega(f(n))$ (something which, in full rigor, should be denoted $g\in\Omega(f)$), then $ug(n)=\Omega(f(n))$ for every nonzero $u$.

A trivial remark is that $(f(n))$ always belongs to $\Omega(f(n))$ but many other sequences $(g(n))$ do as well (in general). In any case, since $f(n)=n^2\log(n)$ is a sequence you admit as a reference, your second case is solved by $n^2\log(n)=\Omega(n^2\log(n))$.

As regards your first example, defining $f(n)=\log(n!)$, an easy induction<sup>(1)</sup> yields $f(n)\geqslant\frac12n\log(n)$ for every $n\geqslant1$ hence $f(n)=\Omega(n\log(n))$.

(Or one can use the weak version of [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) $\log(n!)=n\log(n)+o(n\log(n))$ and the general fact that $g(n)=f(n)+o(f(n))$ implies $g(n)=\Omega(f(n))$.)

**Note**

**<sup>(1)</sup>** If $f(n)=\log(n!)$, the induction step $f(n+1)-f(n)\geqslant\frac12\log(n+1)-\frac12\log(n)$ is equivalent to the inequality $n\log(1+1/n)\leqslant\log(n+1)$. Since $\log(1+x)\leqslant x$ for every $x$, the LHS is at most $1$ and the RHS is at least $\log(3)>1$ for every $n\geqslant2$. Since $f(1)=0$ and $f(2)=\log(2)=\frac12(2\log(2))$, this proves that the inequality $f(n)\geqslant\frac12n\log(n)$ holds for every $n\geqslant1$.

Comment: Thank you, this one really cleared a couple of things :)

Answer (score 0):

[Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) gives you that $n!\approx(\frac{n}{e})^n$ so $\log{n!}\approx n\log n-n$  Since $\log n \to \infty$ the $n \log n$ dominates.  For $n^2 \log n$ I don't have a simpler form.  It dominates $n^2$ and is dominated by $n^{2+\epsilon}$

Comment: Thank you, now I get how the first example was calculated