# Asymptotic behavior of equation$ O(n\log n)=O(n^{1.1})$

Tags: asymptotics

The following equation should be true:
$O(n\log(n))=O(n^{1.1} )$

Based on the following article, one should see the equation as the left part being an element of the right part. [What are the rules for equals signs with big-O and little-o?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86076/what-are-the-rules-for-equals-signs-with-big-o-and-little-o?newreg=46819427eb81467ebf4d375078463359)

Given that the equation is true, $n\log(n)$ should grow at most as fast as $n^{1.1}$. However, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n\log(n)}{n^{1.1}}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(n)}{n^{0.1}} \rightarrow \infty$. This does not correspond with the statement.

What mistake am I making?

Comment: It goes to $0$ instead of to $\infty$. We have that $n^\epsilon$ grows much faster then $\log(n) $ for $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Be careful with this kind of notation.  In fact the point of the article is that you can use a consistent convention with big-O and little-o notation in which, *if* there's a function on the left and a growth class on the right, then = is interpreted as $\in$.  What you've written does not adhere to that convention, and defies the expectation that any expression $A=B$ should be equivalent to $B=A$ when both expressions make sense.

Comment: Thanks @mjqxxxx! The expression is coming from an academic resource. I suppose the interpretation is the same as having a function on the left and a growth class on the right.

Comment: @kingW3 That's a good point, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is true, really, is this:
$$O(n\log n)=o\bigl(n^{1.1}\bigr).$$